Internal Conversion loses integer precision
I installed Firebase with Auth, Firestore, Functions, per pod and I was filled with alerts that I was solving little by little, after that configure and test firebase functions and works fine. The only one I can't solve is the following:

Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<void, decltype(block())>::value, decltype(block())>::type' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int'

Here!
  int LocalStore::Backfill() const {
      return persistence_-> Run("Backfill Indexes", [&] {
        return index_backfiller_->WriteIndexEntries(this);
      });
    }

App and firebase DB seems to work fine but I don't know what is that and what problem could I have it in the future!

Any help?

Is this C++ code?

this is not Swift nor SwiftUI, change the tags of your post.

You might be looking for React Native or you installed the wrong pod

Yes sorry it's c++, my pod file:     platform :ios, '17.0'
target 'AppName' do
use_frameworks!
Pod dependencies
pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'
pod 'FirebaseAuth'
pod 'FirebaseFirestore'
pod 'Firebase/Functions'
end

Although I do not know the tool you are using, I can read the error message for you and this should help you to answer your question.
So function int LocalStore::Backfill() const wants to return integer, a signed integer. But is fed with unsigned long by statement:
persistence_-> Run("Backfill Indexes", [&] {
        return index_backfiller_->WriteIndexEntries(this);
      });

which returns the type described as
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<void, decltype(block())>::value, decltype(block())>::type

which turns out to be a (aka 'unsigned long'), so unsigned long.
So this is now your decision if such implicit casting is OK. I just want to say that this is a messy way of coding to confuse signed and unsigned and integer and long, even if it works.
IMO you should change Backfill to return unsigned long.

I did an explicit conversion and then manage the error just in case it occurs. With this the warning disappear but I don't know if I could have problems in the future... '        int LocalStore::Backfill() const {
return persistence_->Run("Backfill Indexes", [&] {
auto result = index_backfiller_->WriteIndexEntries(this);
    if (result > std::numeric_limits<int>::max()) {
        std::cerr << "Result too large for int" << std::endl;
        return std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    }
    
    return static_cast<int>(result);
});

} '

auto LocalStore::Backfill() const {
      return persistence_-> Run("Backfill Indexes", [&] {
        return index_backfiller_->WriteIndexEntries(this);
      });
    }

return "auto"

error: Return type of out-of-line definition of 'firebase::firestore::local::LocalStore::Backfill' differs from that in the declaration
